# Django: getting related model values through foreign keyfield and print those in the template

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I am struggling getting the foreign key values and print them in my template.
I know there are a lot of questions that may be similar but I have read those and could not figure out a solution.

models.py:

```
class Fixture(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey('League', blank=True, null=True, related_name="league")
    starting_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    home_team = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    away_team = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    fixture_round = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
         db_table = 'fixture'

class Score(models.Model):
    fixture = models.ForeignKey(Fixture, related_name="score")
    period = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    home_team_score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    away_team_score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'score'
```

views.py:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class InsertedResultsListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'gamestream/results_list.html'
    model = Fixture
    fixtures = Fixture.objects.filter(
        ).values().order_by(
        '-starting_time')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        fixtures = Fixture.objects.filter(
            ).values().order_by(
            '-starting_time')
        context = super(InsertedResultsListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['fixtures'] = {'fixtures': fixtures[:25]}
        return context
```

template:

```
{% for fixture in fixtures.fixtures %}
    {{ fixture.score }}
    {{ fixture.score_set.all }}
{% endfor %}
```

Shouldn't my template code give me access to the foreign key field and its values?
What am I doing wrong? Both code lines in the template do not produce anything.

Thanks,
Vittorio

Comment: What do you think `.values()` is doing when defining your `fixtures` query?

Comment: LOL I knew I was missing something! I copied that from another view that I have and did not think about it. Thanks Peter

Comment: Here you may just want something like `Fixture.objects.all().order_by('-starting_time')`.

Comment: That's correct, much appreciated!